# How does nrpe.d order includes?

Tags: nrpe

I'm running the following version of the nagios-nrpe-server:

`nagios-nrpe-server:
  Installed: 2.12-5ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 2.12-5ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.12-5ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.12-5ubuntu1 0
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages`

I'm trying to include multiple files in the `/etc/nagios/nrpe.d/` folder. The files are named:

`1.base.cfg
2.overrides.cfg`

The last entry in my nrpe.cfg file is: `include_dir=/etc/nagios/nrpe.d/`

The base file contains some commands that I wish to override in the overrides file. It seems that the override is not always working however. On some servers, the override file is loaded first.

Does NRPE not support this type of override?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been discussed in http://sourceforge.net/p/nagios/mailman/message/27333277/ . Looks like version 2.12 exhibits the problem.